# PHP base64_encode() output does not match CryptoJS.enc.Base64()

Tags: javascript, php

I’m running into an issue when using PHP to generate the Hmac message signature for use with a snappay hosted payment page.

I confirmed that my snappay staging account is working correctly by creating the signature using the JavaScript cryptojs library and submitting several test transactions.

However, whenever I try using PHP to generate my message signature the snappay API returns an invalid signature error.

After some troubleshooting it appears that the PHP base64 encoded secret key variable is returning different values than the cryptojs base64 encoded variable.

Please see code snippets below. How can I get the PHP to match to cryptojs encoding?

**PHP:**

```
$payloadRaw = sprintf(
    '%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s',
    $accountid,
    $customerid,
    $merchantid,
    $transactionamount,
    $currencycode,
    $paymentmode,
    $email,         
    $nonceid,
    $requestTimeStamp
);  
$secret_key = 'p2v9Im9+gr4RRts2MddoZm1DcOY+MK7/1LBqU7Ztpdc=';   // Fake key
$secretkeyBase64 = base64_encode($secret_key); // Does not match JavaScript
$signatureHash = hash_hmac('sha256', $payloadRaw, $secretkeyBase64, true);
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var secretkey = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(secret_key);  
var txtnonce = "<?php echo "$nonceid"?>"; 
var txttimestamp = "<?php echo "$requestTimeStamp"?>";  
var prehash = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(payloadRaw);    
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(prehash, secretkey);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var signatureData = hashInBase64 + ":" + txtnonce + ":" + txttimestamp;
var prehash1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(signatureData);      
var HmacValueJS = prehash1.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

**Input - payloadRaw:**

8373936484997002300349998556100.00USDCCsample@email.com6ad552829665012b695bbdf72ae2ab31de7e6eac7a94a6d4fa9412cda1961c7a1649797291

**Output - Example Signatures and Secret Key encoding:**

*Signature Correct JS Base64:*
ZUUvTjBxMG55NUlteUxvMWVJeUd3cUo3cXViakNOWkpkaytOQUd6U3lSaz06NmFkNTUyODI5NjY1MDEyYjY5NWJiZGY3MmFlMmFiMzFkZTdlNmVhYzdhOTRhNmQ0ZmE5NDEyY2RhMTk2MWM3YToxNjQ5Nzk3Mjkx

*SecretKey CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse JS:* a76bfd226f7e82be1146db3631d768666d4370e63e30aeffd4b06a53b66da5d7

*Signature Wrong PHP Base64:*
SnhUMTBWRnZBS2txYThld2JhTlVnenJudzRzMVAvYUpldjlrYXRPS0xvST06NmFkNTUyODI5NjY1MDEyYjY5NWJiZGY3MmFlMmFiMzFkZTdlNmVhYzdhOTRhNmQ0ZmE5NDEyY2RhMTk2MWM3YToxNjQ5Nzk3Mjkx

*SecretKey base64_encode PHP:* cDJ2OUltOStncjRSUnRzMk1kZG9abTFEY09ZK01LNy8xTEJxVTdadHBkYz0=

Comment: Can you share some example input and output data for both as well? Also, are you sure it's specifically the base64 encoding that differs and none of the other functions you're using?

Comment: In your PHP the "secret key" is already base64-encoded, and then you encode it a _second_ time when you should likely be _decoding_ it.

Comment: `base64_encode($secret_key)` encodes the (already encoded) string while `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(secret_key)` in your JS decodes it.

Comment: Oh, so I should perform a base64_decode($secret_key) in the PHP?

Comment: You should do the same in both versions. If it is decoding the key or use the encoded one is up to you. But if you perform different tasks on the keys and data, you will ofc get different results.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. How do I give you credit for answering my question?

Comment: I've actually voted to close this as a typo question (since you simply used the wrong function) and that it won't be of much help for future visitors. And for the future, if someone edits your question to format it properly, please don't keep reverting the changes.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think it automatically reverted the edits when I added two additional changes to the post.